# using cp -p onto NFS mount on ZFS filesystem fails

Tags: permissions, zfs

I am trying to copy from an Ubuntu machine to a OmniOS ZFS pool shared via NFS.  When I run the below command, I get:

```
cp: failed to preserve ownership for `./test.txt': Invalid argument
```

The thing is that the file copies fine but the permissions look like this at the destination:

```
-rw-------   1 nobody nogroup   7 Mar  4 21:35 test.txt
```

I then try:

```
chown root test.txt
chown: changing ownership of `test.txt': Invalid argument
```

I found this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/173392/ubuntu-cp-p-on-mounted-zfs-pool) that is similar, but his/her error is more explicit with an "operation not permitted" error, whereas mine is "Invalid argument".

NFS is shared out from the ZFS server via below:

```
cat /etc/dfs/sharetab
/pool1/backup      -       nfs     sec=sys,rw=@192.168.1.21,root=@192.168.1.21
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because I am mounting as NFSv4, and version 4 treats root permissions as 'nobody'.  Forcing my NFS client to use NFS version 3 resolved my issue.

```
nfs -t nfs -o nfsvers=3,proto=tcp server:/pool1/backup /backup
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the owner-group through [idmap](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-idmapd.conf/)

into `/etc/idmapd.conf`

```
[Mapping]

Nobody-User = anyUserYouChoose
Nobody-Group = anyUserYouChoose
```